# Can't find why my code is repeating in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

This block of code keeps repeating and I can't find out why. I am using python 2.7.

```
def source():
    print "What is the source of the emails that you want to sort?"
    start_source = raw_input("> ")
    print "The source is: \"" + start_source + "\" is this correct? Enter yes/no/y/n"
    answer = raw_input("> ")
    if answer == "no" or "n":
        source()
    return start_source
source()
```

Comment: Give a return statement in the if condition

Comment: @bigbounty i added one and it still repeats

Comment: I told inside if,not outside if